# Synonym for "he's senseless"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, synonyms

> He's senseless since yesterday.

Can I say the quoted sentence as

> His sense didn't (return/come back)(i) since yesterday

–if not, what will be appropriate at position (i)?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the first sentence is supposed to be saying. "Senseless" can mean a few different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to say *His senses* (meaning sight, hearing etc.) *have not come back*. *Sense* in the singular would be taken to mean *common sense*.

However, the most idiomatic version would be *He has been unconscious since yesterday.*